# Haskell right-sided recursion to left-sided recursion

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, recursion, selector

In my problem i have list of lists, and i want to find list of lists being selectors (selector - list containing exactly one element from each list), satisfying special condition.

The code to generate all selectors would look like:

```
selectors :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
selectors [] = [[]]
selectors (y:ys) = [ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys]
```

If i wanted to add some extra condition this would be like

```
selectors :: [[a]] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]]
selectors [] _ = [[]]
selectors (y:ys) f = [ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys f, f xs]
```

However in my problem, i need the condition to be dependable on element being candidate for a list, and what's in list i currently build. So this would be something like:

```
selectors :: [[a]] -> ( a-> [a] -> Bool) -> [[a]]
selectors [] _ = [[]]
selectors (y:ys) f = [ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys f, f x xs]
```

And this is working very slow, because at first the recursion goes in very deeply and real work starts from there, whereas this would be MUCH faster if building list was going from left, so whenever i try to add new element to my list and i know this cannot be added so i'd just try to add new element. How can i make this work this way?

Comment: Not certain I completely understand the question, but it seems that your components of your list comprehension could commute which would change the recursion order. Try: `[ (x:xs) | xs <- selectors ys f, x <- y, f x xs ]`?

Comment: Wow, this worked! I was thinking for so long and solution was so simple.

Comment: It just causes the order of the loops to be reversed. I'll write out a longer explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order of some searches by commuting the loop bodies.

```
for i in foo                foo j in bar
  for j in bar     versus     foo i in foo
    do(i, j)                    do(i, j)
```

The same effect can be achieved in list comprehension syntax. For the given example, it might be

```
[ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys f, f x xs ]
-- versus
[ (x:xs) | xs <- selectors ys f, x <- y, f x xs ]
```

If we're only considering the result as a set of values (i.e. the order is immaterial) then the values are identical. Regarded as a set, the only rules considering order of list comprehension clauses are that referenced variables must be bound in clauses left of their reference site.

Let's desugar this notation a bit to see the mechanics at work in higher fidelity.

---

List comprehensions are (almost) equivalent to `do`-notation in the list monad. Without necessarily diving into what monads are, I'll claim that our list comprehension desugars like this

```
-- [ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys f, f x xs ]
-- becomes...

do x  <- y
   xs <- selectors ys f
   guard (f x xs)
   return (x:xs)
```

The translation should be obvious—each generator clause containing `(<-)` becomes a `do`-syntax binding form. Each guard clause becomes a `do`-notation form using the (perfectly normal) function `guard :: Bool -> [()]`. Finally, the translation preserves order.

But now, `do`-notation is just syntax sugar itself! It desugars to a series of function applications. Again, to not dive into the meaning of monads, I'll just do this transformation exactly.

```
-- [ (x:xs) | x <- y, xs <- selectors ys f, f x xs ]
-- becomes...

y >>= (\x -> selectors ys f >>= (\xs -> guard (f x xs) >> return (x:xs)))
```

In particular, each generator line like `x <- E` becomes `E >>= (\x -> ...)` where the `...` corresponds to the translation of the remainder of the `do` block. Lines like `E` without binding arrows translate to `E >> ...`. We can even simplify this one level further by noting that `E >> F` is nothing more than `E >>= (\_ -> F)` so that ultimately we have

```
y >>= (\x -> selectors ys f >>= (\xs -> guard (f x xs) >>= (\_ -> return (x:xs))))
```

And as a final step, we can translate the `(>>=)`, `guard`, and `return` functions to the format they take for the list monad. In particular `ls >>= f` is equal to `concat (map f ls)` and `return x = [x]`. It's actually convenient to write `(>>=)` in a prefix instead of infix form, as well, so we'll call it `forl :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]`.

The function `guard` is a little strange. It looks like `guard b = if b then [()] else []`. We'll see how it works in a moment.

```
forl y $ \x ->
  forl (selectors ys f) $ \xs ->
    forl (guard (f x xs)) $ \_ ->
      [x:xs]
```

Now this is a full translation. If we can understand this then we've understood the mechanics of the list comprehension. For comparison, this is how the list comprehension desugars when we switch the order of the generator clauses

```
forl y $ \x ->                             forl (selectors ys f) $ \xs ->
  forl (selectors ys f) $ \xs ->             forl y $ \x ->
    forl (guard (f x xs)) $ \_ ->              forl (guard (f x xs)) $ \_ ->
      [x:xs]                                     [x:xs]
```

which looks very similar to the imperative example given at the beginning. Let's show that it's actually identical.

---

First, we can dispatch how `forl (guard (f x xs)) $ \_ -> [x:xs]` works. We'll just inline the definition of `guard` and then `forl`

```
forl (if (f x xs) then [()] else []) (\_ -> [x:xs])
concat (map (\_ -> [x:xs]) (if (f x xs) then [()] else []))
```

We can "lift" the `if` out of the inside by noting that once we've wrapped the whole thing in an outer lift, the value of `(f x xs)` is fixed in both the `then` and `else` branches.

```
if (f x xs)
  then concat (map (\_ -> [x:xs]) [()]
  else concat (map (\_ -> [x:xs]) []
```

And finally, we can inline the `map`s and then the `concat`s

```
if f x xs
  then concat [(\_ -> [x:xs]) ()]
  then concat []

if f x xs then [x:xs] else []

forl y $ \x ->                             forl (selectors ys f) $ \xs ->
  forl (selectors ys f) $ \xs ->             forl y $ \x ->
    if f x xs then [x:xs] else []              if f x xs then [x:xs] else []
```

And now it ought to be increasingly clear how these "for" loops work. They loop over a body and produce a list of the results. Since we expect that the body will also be a `forl` loop, we have to anticipate that the value in the body is a list itself—this we flatten that extra layer of lists using `concat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this really exhaustive answer!